# What are bitcoin/altcoin block notifications?

Tags: mining-pools

While setting up a private nomp mining pool as a learning project, The instructions recommended setting up block notify. What are block notifications?

Answer (score 1):

The `-blocknotify="{cmd}"` is one of the [configurable settings](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin) when starting the bitcoin daemon. For example, I can start my bitcoind with this command:

```
bitcoind -blocknotify='echo %s'
```

And when a new block is solved, the block hash gets printed.

```
00000000000000000e979c4a51dc6cb9606e47a2b499f591645f53fe801ae374
```